# How Do I start on Premise: B ↔ ￢B Conclusion: J ↔ ￢C?

Tags: logic

I have started a new chapter and I do not quite understand how you start questions like these? Do i need to just keep doing contradictions to get an answer like this? Can someone point me in the right direction or help me?
**Premise: B ↔ ￢B Conclusion: J ↔ ￢C**

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. First, it is unclear what "this problem" is. B ↔ ￢B leads to a contradiction from which anything follows by the [law of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), for example. But second, we do not know what course you are taking and where you are at in it, hence what sorts of arguments/derivations you are supposed to give, and based on what. You have to describe that in your post, along with your attempts to solve it.

Comment: What textbook are you using and which problem is that in the textbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to start the problem is to put the premise and conclusion in a proof checker and then use the inference rules programmed into the proof checker to reach the conclusion. For this problem since the premises lead to a contradiction whether you start with "B" or "¬B", you can use the law of the excluded middle to reach any result.

Here is how I did it using the proof checker linked to below with a text book explaining the rules in more detail.

[image]

To use the law of the excluded middle I considered both case "B" on lines 2-5 and case "¬B" on lines 6-9.  I reached the same conclusion using explosion (X) on lines 5 and 9 and finished by invoking the law of the excluded middle (LEM) on line 10.

This may not match what you need to do but hopefully it provides a hint how you might proceed.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/